# Calculating normal in fragment shader without glNormal

Tags: opengl, shader

I want to write a fragment shader to render an object with lightning, but without using the gl_Normal; So I must calculate the normal by myself.

I think I could use the functions dFdx and dFdy to find two tangent vectors and then get the normal with the vectorial product of those.

But I don't know which parameter to send to those functions.

Comment: Do you need a per pixel smoothed normal, or just per face?

Answer (score 5):

> I think I could use the functions dFdx and dFdy to find two tangent vectors and then get the normal with the vectorial product of those.

If you did that, you would only get face normals. And if you're doing faceted rendering, that'd be fine. And the "parameter to send to those functions" would be the fragment's position, in whatever space it is you're doing your lighting in. So obviously your vertex shader will need to compute that and pass it to the fragment shader.

For the rest of this post, I'll assume that you're *not* doing faceted rendering. That you want smooth normals to approximate a smooth surface.

The whole point of such normals is that they represent the *actual* surface that your polygonal mesh is *approximating*. So if you have a sphere, the normal at each vertex position should always point directly away from the sphere's center, no matter how many vertices you have.

You cannot magic such normals into being; you have to compute them based either on the actual surface or via a heuristic. The heuristic method requires looking at the triangles around the current one. And fragment shaders don't have access to that information.

Everyone uses vertex normals; it's standard practice. There are even special vertex attribute formats to minimize the size of such normals (`GL_INT_2_10_10_10_REV` being the most prominent). So just do it right.